# Eclipse JDT - How to set a breakpoint on an invisible default constructor?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, eclipse-jdt

How do I set a method entry breakpoint to a synthetic default constructor of a non-editable (library) class in eclipse Juno (4.2)?

e.g.

```
public class Foo {}  // can't change that code
//    (...)
Foo foo = new Foo()   // now it should stop
Foo bar = new Foo()  // stop again
```

Is it possible in general?

To further clarify this, I would like to stop **every time** an instance is of Foo is created at runtime, **not** once the class is loaded. In a complex setup, I have to distinguish if foo or bar is creating an instance.

It basically should be the same as a breakpoint on the invisible, synthetic constructor, **without actually adding** that constructor to the code, e.g.

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo(); //break here
}
```

## Solved

For ***.class*** files, the default constructor is listed in the outline view. A method entry breakpoint can be added by right clicking on that.

Comment: comments from #eclipse - MisterD: "breakpoints are identified via qualified name of the class and the member signature. if so, you can just create a class and member that has the same properties and th ebreakpoint would apply to both the source class and the compiled class e.g. take the source class breakpoint, export it and import it on the project where that class is a library class, might work"

Comment: another options might be to set a breakpoint to the constructor of java.lang.Object with a condition to "this.getName().equals("Foo")"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a breakpoint on a default Java constructor in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876430/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-default-java-constructor-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .class files, you can toggle a method entry breakpoint from the Outline view just as usual.  For source files, you'll actually have to add such a constructor to set a breakpoint in it.  The Outline View shows you what's in the file either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the breakpoint on the line "public class Foo". If you normally double-click to set a breakpoint in the marker bar on the left side of the editor, then double click on the class declaration line.

Comment: that's a class loading breakpoint, which would be triggered once, and even when just accessing a static member. I rephrased my question to make it better distinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

I am possibly missing something but you could simply set a break point on the line `Foo bar = new Foo();` and when the debugger stops there step into the code (so hit the *F5* key).

If `Foo` extends any classes that actually implement a default constructor then your debugger will now be at the first `super` class in the hierarchy that has a default constructor.

If Foo doesn't extend any classes, or none of those have a default constructor, then you simply end up in the instantiation of `Object`.

Comment: that's true, I COULD stop at 'foo = new Foo()'. But if you're not sure who's creating this particular instance at runtime, that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any member variables with initializers, then you can put a breakpoint on them. For example:

```
class MyClass {
  private int i = 0; // this line can have a breakpoint in Eclipse
}
```

Else see this question: [How to set a breakpoint on a default Java constructor in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876430/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-default-java-constructor-in-eclipse)

Comment: I don't want to break ONCE the class is loaded, but EVERY TIME an instance is created. I have to extend my example ... ;)

Comment: Edited my answer. Just tested and if the class has initializers that solution posted above should work. Else check that other question there's a hack you can try.

Answer (score 0):

"#eclipse" helped solving it:
The default constructor is shown in the outline view **IF** it's a *.class* file, not if it's a *.java* file. Then setting a method entry breakpoint is possible.