# In Eclipse's Java debugger, how can I set a breakpoint on every object creation of some class?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I would like to have Eclipse's Java debugger debug-suspend the monitored process whenever an object of a particular type (class / interface) gets instantiated.

As a workaround, I can set breakpoints

- on all constructors of that type
- on all constructors of that type's supertypes and subtypes

but

- this is awkward
- neglects instantiation with the default constructor
- may cause false-positive debug suspensions on object instantiations of classes I didn't want to suspend on.

Comment: Note: if there are other constructors, the default constructor must be explicitly declared (meaning it's available for a breakpoint too).  Also, are subtype breakpoints really necessary?  They have to invoke one of the type's constructors

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to set breakpoints on superclasses and subclasses. If you put a breakpoint on every constructor of the class you are interested in then every time an object of that class or a subclass of it is created the debugger will hit one of the breakpoints.

This doesn't work for interfaces because they are never constructed. I can't think of a way of doing it for interfaces.

Remember that the default constructor only exists for a class if you don't define any constructor at all, so as long as you have at least one constructor it won't be possible to instantiate an object of that type without using one of the constructors you have written.

Answer (score 4):

See this answer of [Carlos Heuberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85421/carlos-heuberger) on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876430/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-default-java-constructor-in-eclipse).

You can also set a breakpoint on particular class load if you need it. See this tutorial for [reference](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html#advanced_class)